# preg-replace, xhtml strict, php, & ampersand error

Tags: php, preg-replace, ampersand

Wondering if there is a handy preg_replace or similar function that will change all my `&` to `&amp;` but will not change `&amp;` to `&amp;amp;` (won't change an `&` that is already in the proper format).

I am having problem displaying a page that has (user submitted) `&` and I wanted to change them (from a block of text fetched from mysql) just before displaying in the page.

Help will be appreciated.
Cheers.

PS: I thought of using a str_replace with an & with space on either side, but then I stopped thinking about typos like `Bob &Jenny` in lieu of `Bob & Jenny` (since user submitted).

Comment: It sounds like you're double/partially encoding it. You should figure out why you have encoded and unencoded data together and fix that issue.

Comment: I haven't encoded anything @Drackir, it's just that in xhtml strict, an user submitted sentence having something like `Bob & Jenny` in it will hinder display of the page.

Comment: Where are you getting the extra `&amp;`s from then? Is the user submitting them? I'm just confused as to why your data would ALREADY have `&amp;` in it if you haven't encoded it yet.

Comment: No that part I mentioned just as a cautionary measure. I don't have &amp; there. Thanks anyway. Best.

Comment: If it's not a problem then why not just use the [htmlentities function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `?!` assertion for that:

```
$html = preg_replace('/&(?!#?\w+;)/', "&amp;", $html);
              # or just (?!amp;)
```

This also skips existing &amp; and other &lt; or &#123; entities. But it's certainly not faultless.